# Customize Exception Template by Bundle

Tags: php, symfony

How to customize exception by bundle?

Example:
I have two bundles: BackendBundle and FrontEndBundle. I want this two bundles to be handled by two different templates when `error 404` is thrown.

How can I do that?

I had read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html but still got no clues.

Comment: Do you mean the error pages or the exception pages (shown in dev)?

Comment: @Pazi: i mean the error page when we `thrown createNotFoundException()`

Answer (score 1):

Like in the [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) mentioned, extend the `TwigBundle` and the `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController:findTemplate`. There you can decide (if it's not in debug) which 404 to show.

This example assumes all you backend routes are reachable under `/backend`. Change it to your needs, or use other things from the request to determine your backend 404s.

```
namespace Acme\ErrorBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseController;

/**
 * ExceptionController.
 */
class ExceptionController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $format
     * @param integer $code       An HTTP response status code
     * @param Boolean $debug
     *
     * @return TemplateReference
     */
    protected function findTemplate(Request $request, $format, $code, $debug)
    {
        // find template for backend 404 errors
        if (!$this->debug && 404 == $code && false !== strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/backend')) {
            $template = new TemplateReference('TwigBundle', 'Exception', 'backend404', $format, 'twig');
            if ($this->templateExists($template)) {
                return $template;
            }
        }

        // the parent method finds the error404.html.twig for the frontend
        return parent::findTemplate($request, $format, $code, $debug);
    }
}
```

Also to mention, the ErrorBundle must inherit from the TwigBundle.

Comment: yes, i had read that. but how to tell symfony. if the error source is from BackendBundle, then use template from backend bundle? Can you give a bit snippet code how to that?

Comment: Exceptionally I coded it for you, but normally it's really easy to determine which method to override for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to the `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` event and override the response that will be sent to the browser. I wrote a quick gist for you:

https://gist.github.com/bezhermoso/87716a9c72a1d12c5036

However, `$event->getRequest()->get('_controller')` will return `null` on 404 errors, obviously. So you have to account for that instance.

Comment: Will take a look of this night :D

Comment: @Pazi So what will you suggest then?

Comment: @GusDeCooL: To not loose the default error reporting on dev environment, you can always check `$container->getParameter('kernel.environment')` and simply not call `$event->setResponse(...)`.

Comment: Check `$event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` and `$event->isMasterRequest()` also.